# Camera preview rotated on some devices

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have been for a while with camera preview on some tablet devices. On most of the top-end devices works well, however on this cheap tablet the preview is completely upside down like the one on the picture:
[image: Camera Preview]

Is there a way to manually rotate the preview?

EDIT 1:
I'm using cwac-cam2 library;

EDIT 2:
Seems its not just eStar (low-budget one), Asus MemoPad 7 as well has rotated preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the preview is completely upside down like the one on the picture

Um, the picture does not show a "completely upside down" preview AFAICT. It shows what appears to be a preview rotated 90 degrees (a woman standing on the floor appears to be standing on a wall in the preview). The expression "upside down" is usually reserved for a 180-degree rotation (a woman standing on the floor appears to be standing on the ceiling in the preview).

> Is there a way to manually rotate the preview?

No.

> Seems its not just eStar (low-budget one), Asus MemoPad 7 as well has rotated preview

Please read [the project's contribution guidelines](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md), then post an [issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues) (or two, in this case, if you prefer, one per device). Be certain to include **complete steps for reproducing the issue**. In this case, that would include the code necessary to reproduce the problem (if you cannot reproduce it with the project's demo apps), along with enough device identifiers that I can reliably procure this hardware. Notably, there are several devices marketed as an Asus MemoPad 7, not even including the HD variant. There also seem to be a few different tablets marketed under the eStar brand.

Now, I happen to be revamping the camera preview stuff right now, so there's an off chance that I'll semi-unintentionally happen to fix this problem as a part of that, but I wouldn't hold out much hope. That's why, to fix this, I need to be able to reproduce the problem here in the lab, so that I can figure out what is going on.